# Some doubts related how to handle model object into a .NET view that use Jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am pretty new in C# \ .NET and I have the following doubts.

I am working on this Jquery page of a webapplication:

```
@model MyUsers.Models.SearchGroups
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/MasterPageAdminMobile.cshtml";

    WebGrid wGrid = new WebGrid(null, rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize, defaultSort: "NOME", canPage: false);
    wGrid.Bind(Model.Gruppi, rowCount: Model.TotalRows, autoSortAndPage: false);
}

<h2>Gruppi</h2>

<a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Groups")"  data-icon="plus"  data-inline="true" data-mini="true"  data-role="button"  >Crea un nuovo gruppo</a>

@if (Model.TotalRows == 0)
{
    <h3>Non è stato trovato nessun gruppo. Modificare i filtri di ricerca.</h3>
}
else
{

    <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
        @wGrid.GetHtml(
            fillEmptyRows: false,
            tableStyle: "MyTable ui-responsive",
            headerStyle: "ui-bar-c",
            footerStyle: "ui-bar-b",
            rowStyle: "ui-bar-a",
            alternatingRowStyle: "ui-bar-b",
            htmlAttributes: new { data_role = "table", id = "MyWebGrid", data_mode = "reflow" },
            columns: new[]{
                wGrid.Column ("Nome","", canSort  : true),
                wGrid.Column ("countUsers","Numero utenti", canSort  : false ),
                 wGrid.Column ("countRoles","Numero ruoli", canSort  : false ),
                wGrid.Column ("", header :"Actions",  format:@<text>
        <a class="ui-btn-inline ui-btn ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all"   href="@Url.Action("Details", "Groups", new { id = item.gruppoId })">Info</a>
        <a class="ui-btn-inline ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all" href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Groups", new { id = item.gruppoId })">Delete</a>
        </text>, canSort : false)
                }
            )

        @{Html.RenderPartial("Paging", Model);}
    </div>
}
```

This page show a table containing some rows.

My doubts are:

1) It seems to me that the content of these rows are taken from the element of the **Model.Gruppi** collection. So if I want create another table containing the information that are stored into the object inside a list I simply have to declare something like it:

```
wGrid.Bind(Model.MyCollection, rowCount: Model.TotalRows, autoSortAndPage: false);
```

Is it true or am I missing something?

2) It seems to me that the model object is declared using:

```
@model MyUsers.Models.SearchGroups
```

but why when it access to an object field it referer to it using **Model**, is it a standard name of the model object?

Comment: point 2) Yes, Model is the public property that is available that allows access to the view model that is passed to this view when its executed. In your case, as you're aware, Model is of type SearchGroups

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, you are correct in your assumption that the grid is bound to items in the Gruppi collection on your model, ie `MyUsers.Models.SearchGroups.Gruppi`. This is referenced in the view as `Model.Gruppi`.

If you would like to create another grid in the view you can use either the WebGrid constructor by itself, or a combination of the constructor and the Bind method as you have listed in your code above. The call to Bind offers the ability to pass in additional data required for paging the grid rows. There are a number of parameters available on both the constructor and Bind methods. The following provides a thorough overview of the options available:

[Get the Most out of WebGrid in ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx)

2) The model directive at the top of the view

```
@model MyUsers.Models.SearchGroups
```

indicates that this is a strongly typed view that is bound to a model of type `MyUsers.Models.SearchGroups`. ASP.Net Mvc strongly typed views use `Model` to refer to the instance of the model that is bound to the view. So in your view `Model.Gruppi` refers to the Gruppi property on your model.